# How can I send message without bot.polling() using telebot on Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to send message but without any polling. My bot don't have to reply to any message It just needs to send.

```
import telebot


bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])


def send_message(message, text):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text)

text = "Text that I want to be sent"
send_message(text)
bot.polling()

print("Message has been sent")
```

Here is two problems:

1. I can't call a function send_message and pass an argument "text"
   in it
2. After sending a message I want my program to work further, and not
   check the chat for messages

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: @jalazbe, I supplemented my question with code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bot.send_message(msg_id, "Hello!")` (msg_id is person's id) will help you do that if you know the person's id.

If you don't, it is easily obtainable using `msg.chat.id` where `msg` is a message sent by the user.

Comment: And how can I find out my id

Comment: You may use this bot: ```@userinfobot``` or just text your own bot and get ```msg.chat.id```